# Python Selenium Table Body Data Extraction

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, datatables

I am trying to get the data elements of class `td` from my table, but my code consistently is only capable of pulling the rows from the `thead`. If I add `find_element_by_tag_name("tbody")`, then I get the classic *Message: no such element: Unable to locate element...*. Any tips?

**Source Code**: from https://shinyapps.asee.org/apps/Profiles/

```
<table class="cell-border stripe compact dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_4" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_4_info">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            .
            .
            .
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            .
            .
            .
         </tr>
         .
         .
         .
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Selenium Python**:

```
for opt in element.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.option"):
    #Record College Names
    colleges.append(opt.get_attribute("data-value"))
    time.sleep(2)
    #Select College
    opt.click() #does pull data into graph
    #Scrape Data
    table = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table")
    alldata = table.find_element_by_tag_name("tbody")
    rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
    #print(table.tag_name)
    for row in rows:
        print(row.tag_name)
        data = []
        data.append(year)
        data.append("Degrees Awarded")
        data_elements = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        #add to pandas table
        for fact in data_elements:
            try:
                data.append(fact.text)
            except:
                print("nothing")
        print(data)
        #DF.loc[len(DF.index)]=data
    #reclick on dropdown box to get next school's data
    element.click()
```

Comment: Sometimes people leave out the `tbody` element from a table, but most browsers seem to insert one automatically. Check the raw source (not the element inspector) of the page to see if the table actually contains a `tbody`. If not, you should just be able to get the rows (`tr`) from the `table` directly.

Comment: I tried not including the tbody line, and it is only returning the tr from the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two table elements - one for the **Header** (without `id` attribute) and other for the **Data** (with `id` attribute).

Try like below and confirm.

```
driver.get("https://shinyapps.asee.org/apps/Profiles/")

# Code to select "Degrees Awarded" and other option in the drop down.

table_header = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[not(@id)]//th")

header_row = []
for header in table_header:
    header_row.append(header.text)

print(header_row)

table_data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[@id]/tbody/tr")

for row in table_data:
    columns = row.find_elements(By.XPATH,"./td") # Use dot in the xpath to find elements with in element.
    table_row = []
    for column in columns:
        table_row.append(column.text)
    print(table_row)
```

```
['INSTITUTIONS', 'DEGREE NAME', 'DISCIPLINE NAME', 'NON RES ALIEN M', 'NON RES ALIEN F', 'UNKNOWN M', 'UNKNOWN F', 'HISPANIC M', 'HISPANIC F', 'AMERICAN INDIAN M', 'AMERICAN INDIAN F', 'ASIAN AMERICAN M', 'ASIAN AMERICAN F', 'AFRICAN AMERICAN M', 'AFRICAN AMERICAN F', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Air Force Institute of Technology', 'Aeronautical Engineering (M.S)', 'Aerospace Engineering', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '17', '4', '0', '0', '23']
['Air Force Institute of Technology', 'Applied Mathematics (M.S)', 'Other Engineering Disciplines', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1']
...
```

To get the `id` attribute of the table element, you can use below lines.

```
table_id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table[@id]").get_attribute("id")
print(table_id)
```

```
DataTables_Table_3
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! Do you have a method for getting the table id? The id changes as the app is manipulated, and I haven't figured out the pattern.

Comment: @NikkiGorrell - Have updated the answer to extract the table id. If the answer was helpful, do accept the same. Click on the rignt-mark option available at the left side of the answer.